# Rails problems with root_path get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

thanks for you expert advise. If this question is off-topic or not appropriate, please just comment or mail me and I will delete it.

I am building a Ruby on Rails application which uses two different Layouts. The first page is an introductory page set as root for the application, where the new User can display some basic information about the App and then Log In or Sign Up.

The first page has a perfectly working *layout* **main.html.erb** and a *view* **main/welcome.html.erb**.

When the User clicks the Signup link, the devise view for the Sign Up is called.

```
<%= link_to "Sign Up", new_account_registration_path  %>
```

As the Application Controller has a second **user** layout, it displays all the views in this layout without problems.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    layout "user"

    protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

In the view *registration/new* I have another link, that allows the user to cancel the registration and return to the homepage and root of the application (rendering the *layout* **main.html.erb** and the *view* **main/welcome.html.erb**).

If I use the Root path with the **method: :get** the root page will load without having any problem. Both the **layout** and **view** will load.

```
<%= link_to "Cancel", root_path, method: :get, :class => "btn btn-default wideButton" %>
```

If I use the root_path without the get method, some of the content will not load.
This is the result:

[image]

The homepage will load, but only with the navbar, while the rest of the HTML content will not load.

In the case I use :method => :get, the page works, and this is the result.
The main difference is that in the first case (not working) there is a get request to /, while in the second case (the page loads) the browser displays a post request to /.

[image]

This is the log of the non working scenario. Also I would ask what are the risk in this case of not calling the cancel_account_registration_path.

Thanks a lot. 
Best Regards
Fabrizio Bertoglio

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-02-06 15:03:37.531 [fyi] Started GET "/account/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-06 15:03:37 +0100 (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:37.548 [meh] ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations` (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:37.570 [fyi] Processing by Account::RegistrationsController#new as HTML (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:37.600 [fyi] Rendering account/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/user (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:37.605 [fyi] Rendered partials/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms) (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:37.643 [fyi] Rendered account/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/user (42.8ms) (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:37.982 [fyi] Completed 200 OK in 411ms (Views: 386.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms) (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:40.211 [fyi] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-06 15:03:40 +0100 (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:40.213 [fyi] Processing by MainController#welcome as HTML (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:40.215 [fyi] Rendering main/welcome.html.erb within layouts/main (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:40.217 [fyi] Rendered main/welcome.html.erb within layouts/main (1.5ms) (pid:9730)
2017-02-06 15:03:40.280 [fyi] Completed 200 OK in 67ms (Views: 65.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) (pid:9730)
```

This is the log of the working functionality.

```
>> rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.2 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-02-06 15:12:00.775 [fyi] Started GET "/account/sign_up" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-06 15:12:00 +0100 (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:00.796 [meh] ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations` (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:00.825 [fyi] Processing by Account::RegistrationsController#new as HTML (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:00.859 [fyi] Rendering account/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/user (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:00.863 [fyi] Rendered partials/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms) (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:00.908 [fyi] Rendered account/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/user (49.0ms) (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:01.242 [fyi] Completed 200 OK in 416ms (Views: 386.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms) (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.500 [fyi] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-06 15:12:04 +0100 (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.503 [fyi] Processing by MainController#welcome as HTML (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.503 [fyi] Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"n52C8V3Z6S8FrACAWJeU+IIAfBy2N/7rWIV+338pDTBHmvCQq0JvKOA9zhEgvy7IgGIPvexP3Du8db10lm9AVA=="} (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.505 [fyi] Rendering main/welcome.html.erb within layouts/main (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.508 [fyi] Rendered main/welcome.html.erb within layouts/main (2.1ms) (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.539 [fyi] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-06 15:12:04 +0100 (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.547 [fyi] Processing by MainController#welcome as HTML (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.550 [fyi] Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"n52C8V3Z6S8FrACAWJeU+IIAfBy2N/7rWIV+338pDTBHmvCQq0JvKOA9zhEgvy7IgGIPvexP3Du8db10lm9AVA=="} (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.569 [fyi] Rendering main/welcome.html.erb within layouts/main (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.575 [fyi] Rendered main/welcome.html.erb within layouts/main (1.1ms) (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.597 [fyi] Completed 200 OK in 94ms (Views: 92.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) (pid:9893)
2017-02-06 15:12:04.639 [fyi] Completed 200 OK in 77ms (Views: 73.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) (pid:9893)
```

Comment: Where are the `POST` requests in those logs?

Comment: @Iceman If I create an account (signup) I get POST "/account" in my server log, if I log out I get DELETE "/account/sign_out". 
When I click the link for going back to the root (root_path with method get) my log it displays:
 Started GET "/"
While in my browser network console POST /
This link is inside a form_for with url: registration_path(resource_name). It is the form for submitting a new registration.

Comment: Its bad practice to put layout "user" in the ApplicationController, put that where I imagine it belongs, which is the UserController.